# Ordenar lista em ordem alfabética com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho um HTML simples onde preciso de uma lista de nomes que eu consiga adicionar, remover e de dois botões que ordene por ordem crescente e decrescente.

Eu consegui fazer somente o adicionar e o remover da lista.

```js
var convidados = new Array();

function InsereConvidado() {
  var conv = document.getElementById("convidado");
  if (conv.value !== '') {
    convidados.push(conv.value);
    conv.value = '';
    AtualizaLista();
  }
}

function AtualizaLista() {
  if (convidados.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("presentes").innerHTML = "";
    convidados = convidados.sort();
    for (i = 0; i < convidados.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById("presentes").innerHTML += '<li><span id="nome">' + convidados[i] + '</span> <span onClick="RemoverConvidado(this);" style="color: red;">[x]</span></li>';
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("presentes").innerHTML = "Nenhum convidado na lista.";
  }
}

function RemoverConvidado(el) {
  var nome = el.parentNode.firstChild.innerHTML;
  for (i = 0; i < convidados.length; i++) {
    if (convidados[i] === nome) {
      convidados.splice(i, 1);
      AtualizaLista();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h4>Lista de Presentes</h4>
<ul id="presentes">Nenhum convidado na lista.</ul>

<h4>Inserir Convidado</h4>
<input type="text" placeholder="Nome do Convidado" id="convidado" />
<button type="button" onClick="InsereConvidado();">Inserir</button>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a adicionar dois botões nesta lista? Um que ordene por ordem crescente os nomes e outro que ordene por ordem decrescente.

Comment: Se o código for simples, é preferível que coloque ele dentro da pergunta.

Comment: Um você quer A-Z e ou Z-A é isso?

Comment: eu prefiro deixar ele aonde está pois ficar mais facil de ser executado, e tbm eu não sei como criar aquela parte de executar o codigo dentro do post desculpa ;\

Comment: isso, são dois botoes uma de A-Z e outra de Z-A

Comment: @Tibialize respondi, ve se funciona qualquer coisa me avisa e se possível marque como correta :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui fazer de forma simples:

```js
var convidados = new Array();

function OrdenarInvertido() {
var conv = document.getElementById("convidado");

                conv.value = '';
    convidados = convidados.sort();
    convidados = convidados.reverse(); 
        document.getElementById("presentes").innerHTML = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < convidados.length; i++) {
              document.getElementById("presentes").innerHTML += '<li><span id="nome">' + convidados[i] + '</span> <span onClick="RemoverConvidado(this);" style="color: red;">[x]</span></li>';
    }

    }
    function Ordenar() {
    var conv = document.getElementById("convidado");

                conv.value = '';
    convidados = convidados.sort();
        document.getElementById("presentes").innerHTML = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < convidados.length; i++) {
              document.getElementById("presentes").innerHTML += '<li><span id="nome">' + convidados[i] + '</span> <span onClick="RemoverConvidado(this);" style="color: red;">[x]</span></li>';
    }

    }

        function InsereConvidado() {
            var conv = document.getElementById("convidado");
            if (conv.value !== '') {
                convidados.push(conv.value);
                conv.value = '';
                AtualizaLista();
            }
        }


        function AtualizaLista() {
            if (convidados.length > 0) {
                document.getElementById("presentes").innerHTML = "";
                convidados = convidados.sort();
                for (i = 0; i < convidados.length; i++) {
                    document.getElementById("presentes").innerHTML += '<li><span id="nome">' + convidados[i] + '</span> <span onClick="RemoverConvidado(this);" style="color: red;">[x]</span></li>';
                }
            } else {
                document.getElementById("presentes").innerHTML = "Nenhum convidado na lista.";
            }
        }

        function RemoverConvidado(el) {
            var nome = el.parentNode.firstChild.innerHTML;
            for (i = 0; i < convidados.length; i++) {
                if(convidados[i] === nome) {
                        convidados.splice(i, 1);
                    AtualizaLista();
                    }
            }
        }
```

```html
<title>Exercício</title>
<body>
    <h4>Lista de Presentes</h4>
    <ul id="presentes">Nenhum convidado na lista.</ul>

    <h4>Inserir Convidado</h4>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nome do Convidado" id="convidado" />
    <button type="button" onClick="InsereConvidado();">Inserir</button>
  <button type="button" onClick="Ordenar();">Ordenar</button>
  <button type="button" onClick="OrdenarInvertido();">Ordenar Invertido</button>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo que eu queria @Breno, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda

Answer (score -1):

A sua função atualizar já ordena por ordem crescente. Para fazer por ordem decrescente, é só criar uma cópia da sua função atualizar e colocar `convidados = convidados.reverse()` após `convidados = convidados.sort();`. Depois é só atribuir os cliques dos botões a essas funções.

Comment: como que eu faço isso?

Comment: pode me dar um exemplo

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9afggkr7/

Utilizei o seu mesmo método de Atualizar, alterando-o para receber um parâmetro que indica se a ordenação deve ocorrer em ordem crescente ou decrescente.